# Mobile Browser (iPad/iPhone/iPod/Android) crashes when updating image continuously javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, mobile-safari, data-uri

we are trying to update the image src with base64 string using data URIs on our webpage every second with Java Script.

Java Script(AJAX) gets the latest image from webserver.

But all mobile browsers crashing after 5-10 mins. crash dump says, browser is crashing because of low memory.

is there any way to cleanup the memory programatically.

thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Kartheek

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself but according to a comment on this webpage:

[cubiq.org/testing-memory-usage-on-mobile-safari](http://cubiq.org/testing-memory-usage-on-mobile-safari)

base64 string images are not properly garbage collected by MobileSafari, causing MobileSafari to crash at what seems random places. I think it's worth trying to use regular image links and see what happens.

Also keep in mind that there is an image data memory limit around 10M.